# WSO2 : Physical Path of the Resource in Governance Registry

Tags: wso2

How can i fetch physical path of a resource such as wsdl that added to wso2 governance registry? 
i want to pars it so need to physical path of it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Governance registry uses a database (h2 by default) to store it's configuration. Therefore, you can't find on the filesystem, the file added into gov (unless you export the registry using checkin-client.bat).

A solution would be to request the wsdl instead of trying to read it's file.

Comment: i want to compare two version of wsdl using a parser that get the wsdl address as a string. but i can have the wsdl content using resource.getContent() method. the comparison component is implemented in repository so i think that request the wsdl is not an interesting approach. whats your opinion? do you have a better approach for example placing comparison component in ESB? thanks.

Comment: What about this comparison component, can you tell me more about it ? Perhaps a useful information for you : inside a mediation, into the ESB, you can load a resource saved into the registry using get-property, for exemple : get-property('gov:/trunk/MyResource')

Comment: i want to compare two version of wsdl to generate delta log file of those. i used of com.predic8.wsdl for parsing and comparing different versions of wsdl. but when i deploy the Handler that contain code of parsing, i encounter by a error caused by com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser(); i dont know why realy! because it done in a typical java project.